# Strange for loop behaviour

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 5 ;
    Console.WriteLine("i" + "   " + "k");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        k--;
        Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + k);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
}
```

The out put is here:

> i  k
>
> 0  4
>
> 1  3
>
> 2  2
>
> 3

Why does it increment `i` one more time after it reaches 2 < 2 which is not true?

Comment: You could use a debugger and step through your code?

Comment: 0 5, 1 4,  2 3. Looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is true `(2 < 3)` and you decrease `K` after the condition is checked, but before the `Console` write, which is causing you the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you print 2,2 the check condition was i = 2 < k = 3 then inside your loop you decrease the value of k.

After you print 2, 2, you increase the value of i to 3 and the loop ends

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 5 ;
    Console.WriteLine("i" + "   " + "k");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + k);
        k--;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
}
```

The order in which you decrement your variable matters.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `i == 3` at the end of the loop can be explained by examining [how a `for` loop works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte). Your code,

```
int i = 0;
int k = 5 ;
Console.WriteLine("i" + "   " + "k");
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    k--;
    Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + k);
}
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

is syntactically equivalent to

```
int i = 0;
int k = 5 ;
Console.WriteLine("i" + "   " + "k");
while ( i < k )
{
    k--;
    Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + k);
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

so the loop continues as long as `i < k`. In other words, at the end of the loop, `i < k` is false. Your program outputs `2 2`, but after that `WriteLine`, `i++` is evaluated *before* the comparison `i < k` is made.

To demonstrate this a bit more, here is the state of `i` and `k` each time the comparison `i < k` is made:

```
i  k  i < k
0  5  true
1  4  true
2  3  true
3  2  false // don't enter the loop
```

The loop exits when `i < k` is not true, which in this case is when `i` is 3 and `k` is 2.